# Netbeans - How can I rename project lib folder when clean and build?

Tags: java, netbeans

I use NetBeans IDE 8.2. I import some jar file to my project. 
When I clean and build project, I get project jar file and lib folder, it contains all import jar file. I hope someone help me how to rename lib folder, possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to right click on desired library and choose Refactoring under that there is Rename, just rename to however you want and click done.

Comment: I want to rename folder contains all import jar file after clean and build project, default name is "lib"